# CMake output from add_custom_command not found

Tags: cmake

As this is my first attempt in writing a proper cmake file I think I need some hints as to where I misunderstood things.

Reading this: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

I thought I could create my icon.c file from image (bmp) files like so:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT icons.c
  COMMAND ${PBRES} -c icons.c -4 "*/*.bmp"
)

target_sources(iconLib
    PRIVATE
        icons.c
)
```

Unfortunately I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    /project/icons/icons.c


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: iconLib
```

The CMakeLists.txt above is in a subdirectory "icons" and gets invoked by its parent which looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

set(PBSDK /SDK_6.3.0/SDK-B288)
# set the project name
project(SGTPuzzles)

add_library(gamesLib "")
add_subdirectory(games)

add_library(iconLib "")
add_subdirectory(icons)
```

**Update**

I moved the custom command into the main CMakeLists.txt like so:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT icons/icons.c
    COMMAND ${PBRES} -c icons/icons.c -4 "icons/*/*.bmp"
)
```

and this seems to work.

Comment: You may not be specifying all the necessary paths.  I believe `add_custom_command` defaults to a working directory in the build.  And a subdirectory in the source tree by default gets a subdirectory in the build tree.  I recommend you start simpler with your first CMake project and only add one additional complicating factor at a time.

Comment: The issue is: It's not my source code, it's just one, where I want to change from Makefile to CMakeLists.txt because the SDK I use comes with cmake in mind. So there is an include file for cmake in the SDK which sets all required paths etc.